# Windows va_arg compilation error, not on linux

Tags: c++, windows

So I am building my own mock package of curl, and I have some annoying behavior when I try and run my code on Windows. On Ubuntu 20 it builds and runs, but as soon as I tried to compile it on windows I get an error. chatGPT hs not been helpful, and I don't know really where to look, if any of you have some ideas it'd be great.

So I have this function:

```
CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLoption option, ...)
{
    auto h = reinterpret_cast<curl_impl*>(handle);
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, option);
    switch (option) {
        case CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION:
            // Set client::writeHeader as the function to be called as soon as mock curl has received header data.
            if (h->testFailureMode == curl_impl::error_mode::header_function_error) {
                va_end(vl);
                return CURLE_UNKNOWN_OPTION;
            }
            h->writeHeader = va_arg(vl, size_t (*)(char*, size_t, size_t, void*));
            break;
        case CURLOPT_HEADERDATA:
            // Pointer to the context to write the header part of the received data to.
            if (h->testFailureMode == curl_impl::error_mode::header_context_error) {
                va_end(vl);
                return CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT;
            }
            h->headerContext = va_arg(vl, void*);
                break;
// More of this function but not needed for the example
```

And when compiling I get this error:

```
mock_curl.cpp(88,30): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Which points to the line `h->writeHeader = va_arg(vl, size_t (*)(char*, size_t, size_t, void*));`
What I don't understand is that the line `h->headerContext = va_arg(vl, void*);` triggers no error. VScode shows me a `"size_t" is ambiguousC/C++(266)` but I don't think it's relevant because replacing it with unsigned int doesn't change anything.

I'd be grateful for any help :)
Thanks

Oh and side note, I based my code of the [leatherman's repo](https://github.com/puppetlabs/leatherman/blob/main/curl/tests/mock_curl.cc)

Comment: Please add a comment in the shown code where you get the error. And please try to create a [mre] to show us, together with the full and complete build-log from that example.

Comment: It's a problem with macro expansion, when a macro argument contains parentheses. Try introducing a type alias; `using function = size_t (*)(char*, size_t, size_t, void*); h->writeHeader = va_arg(vl, function);`

Comment: To add some details to the comment by @molbdnilo, a comma in a funbction-like macro (which `va_arg` likely is) will generally not work very well.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! that was indeed the issue !

Comment: Note in C++ consider using variadic templates. va_args is there for backward compatibility with "C". Also ChatGPT has a lot of problems still with all the nuances in C++, don't use it (yet)

Comment: Also note that Visual Studio has a choice of two different preprocessors, "Standard Conforming" and "Legacy", Of course Legacy is the default, as it has always been.